# Convert Int value to CSS Color (to use with QML Canvas)

Tags: css, canvas, qml

I have a colour value stored as an integer that I get from native code. 
Is there a way I can use this value directly **without** having to separate each invididual RGB component with something like this?

```
var color_val = GetColourFromNativeCode();
var red = (color_val>> 16) & 0xFF;
var green = (color_val>> 8) & 0xFF;
var blue = color_val & 0xFF;
context.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler : use the Qt.rgba () method :

```
context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba ((color_val >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255,
                               (color_val >> 8  & 0xFF) / 255,
                               (color_val       & 0xFF) / 255);
```

That way, Qt engine converts it to an actual 'color' typed variable.